# Generating rel="prev" and rel="next" using filters

Tags: php, pagination

In wp-includes\link-template.php the function which defines the pagination is:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the previous posts page link.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @global int $paged
 *
 * @param string $label Optional. Previous page link text.
 * @return string|void HTML-formatted previous page link.
 */
function get_previous_posts_link( $label = null ) {
    global $paged;

    if ( null === $label )
        $label = __( '&laquo; Previous Page' );

    if ( !is_single() && $paged > 1 ) {
        /**
         * Filters the anchor tag attributes for the previous posts page link.
         *
         * @since 2.7.0
         *
         * @param string $attributes Attributes for the anchor tag.
         */
        $attr = apply_filters( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', '' );
        return '<a href="' . previous_posts( false ) . "\" $attr>". preg_replace( '/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $label ) .'</a>';
    }
}
```

I have tried to define in my theme functions.php the following piece of code:

```
function previous_posts_link_callback() {
    $res = 'rel="prev"';
    return $res;
}
add_filter( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', 'previous_posts_link_callback', 10, 3 );
```

Why it doesn't work?

Comment: The other questions are not duplicate since don't use the filters

Comment: Try removing `, 3`. The `previous_posts_link_attributes` filter doesn't have any additional arguments, so this should be either 1, or not be set at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `, 3`. The previous_posts_link_attributes filter doesn't have any additional arguments, so this should be either `1`, or not be set at all (`1` is the default).

```
add_filter( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', 'previous_posts_link_callback', 10 );
```